# can't read .dbt file: Unknown dbf type

Tags: python, dbf

I get following error when I try to read a `.dbt` file with [this](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/)  library.

```
import dbf

table = dbf.Table(filename='test.dbt')
table.open(dbf.READ_ONLY)

>>dbf.DbfError: Unknown dbf type: 16 (10)
```

You can find the example data [here](https://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/index.shtml.en).

Comment: @itprorh66 The "code" linked is a library with ~10k LOC, not including tests and ancillary files. The data referenced in question is a binary data file, and cannot be included in the question body. Links to external data sources are acceptable under these circumstances.

Comment: Looking around on the xBase site you linked to, I found [this version table](https://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/dbf.html#DBF_NOTE_1_TARGET). `0x10` (or `10h`) is not in there, which is why you're getting the error. Perhaps the fact that it's a DBT file and not a DBF has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dbt` is the memo file, and cannot be opened separately from the `.dbf` file.  What you need to do is

```
table = dbf.Table(filename='test.dbf')
```

and the fields stored in the `.dbt` file will automatically be available.